# Inverse Fourier Transform of a characteristic function of two probability densities

Tags: probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

I am going through the book [Probability and Random Processes for Computer and Electrical Engineers](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/5636840/mod_resource/content/1/probability%20and%20random%20process%20for%20electrical%20and%20computer%20engineering.pdf) for my own understanding. Example 4.23 states that,

Let $Z := X + Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. The characteristic function of $Z$ is the product of the characteristic functions of $X$ and $Y$,

$$
\phi_Z(v) := \mathbb{E}[e^{jvZ}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{jv(X + Y)}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{jvX}e^{jvY}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{jvX}]\mathbb{E}[e^{jvY}] = \phi_X(v)\phi_Y(v)
$$

Which is pretty easy to see because they are independent. I cannot derive the next box though, even though it seems simple. 4.16 says,

> An immediate consequence of the previous example is that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent continuous random variables, then the density of their sum $Z = X + Y$ is the convolution of their densities (which is the inverse Fourier transform of the above example). $$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(z - y)f(y) dy$$

Trying to do this myself, I get stuck in the inverse Fourier transform,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\phi_Z(v) &= \phi_X(v)\phi_Y(v) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

So this means that...

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_Z(z) &= \phi_Z^{-1}(v)  \\ 
&= \phi_X^{-1}(v)\phi_Y^{-1}(v) \\
&= \int e^{-jvz}\phi_X(v) dv \int e^{-jvz}\phi_Y(v) dv \\
&= \iint e^{-jvz}e^{jvx}f(x) dxdv \iint e^{-jvz}e^{jvy}f(y) dydv \\
&= \iint e^{-jv(x-z)}f(x) dxdv \iint e^{-jv(y-z)}f(y) dydv \\
&= \iint e^{-jv(z -y - z)}f(z - y) dydv \iint e^{-jv(y-z)}f(y) dydv \quad \text{change of vars.}\;\; x = z-y\\
&= \iint e^{jvy}f(z - y) dydv \iint e^{-jv(y-z)}f(y) dydv \\
&= \iint e^{jvy}e^{-jv(y-z)}f(z - y)f(y) dydv \\
&= \iint e^{jv(z)}f(z - y)f(y) dydv \\
\end{aligned}
$$

I can see I have all the pieces there, but I am unsure where I went wrong or how to finish it so I get rid of the double integral and achieve the expression in the blockquotes. Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F_X$, $F_Y$, $F_Z$ be the CDF's of $X$, $Y$, $Z$ respectively. Then, for any $u\in \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align*}
F_{Z} (u) &= \mathbb{P}(Z \leq u) = \mathbb{P}(X+Y \leq u)  = \iint_{x+y \leq u} f_{X}(x) f_{Y}(y)dxdy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}(x)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{u-x} f_{Y}(y)dy \right) dx =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}(x) F_Y(u-x) dx.
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
f_Z(u) &= \frac{d}{du} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}(x) F_Y(u-x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}(x) \frac{d}{du} F_Y(u-x) dx \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}(x) f_Y(u-x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}(u-v) f_Y(v) dv.
\end{align*}

Comment: Another approach: Let $\widehat{f}(u) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{i u x} dx$ be the Fourier transform of a integrable function $f$. Let $f_X \ast f_Y$ be the convolution of $f_X$ and $f_Y$. Observe that $\widehat{f_X} = \phi_{X}$, $\widehat{f_Y} = \phi_{Y}$ and $\widehat{f_{Z}} = \phi_{Z}$. It is known from the Fourier theory that $\widehat{f_X \ast f_Y} = \widehat{f_X} \widehat{f_Y} $. Hence, $\widehat{f_X \ast f_Y} = \phi_X \phi_Y = \phi_{X+Y} = \phi_Z = \widehat{f_Z}$. This implies $f_{X} \ast f_Y = f_Z$.

Comment: adding reference for posterity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem